# « Être là » ou « y être » ?

Tags: choix-de-mot

Si Henri parle d'un endroit et il aimerait dire que son collègue n'est pas à cet endroit, il pourrait dire

> Il n'est pas là.

ou bien

> Il n'y est pas.

Je pensais que les deux voulaient dire la même chose, mais je pense qu'en fait je n'ai entendu que rarement le deuxième. Cependant, le deuxième est le plus commun selon Google ngrams. Est-ce que vous pouviez expliquer la différence entre eux ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Il n'est pas là.

Signifie généralement que cette personne n'est pas près de l'endroit où je me trouve.

> Il n'y est pas.

Signifie que cette personne n'est pas à endroit indiqué dans la question.

Answer (score 2):

Si Henri veut répondre négativement à la question " Albert est-il dans sa salle de cours habituelle ?", il dira simplement : "Non, il n'y est pas".

Comment: "Il n'est pas là" est aussi l'équivalent de "Il est absent".